# Como usar o clipboard para copiar e colar

Tags: java, android

Como usar o clipboar do android, para copiar uma um texto de um textView, preciso copiar esse texto e usar para colar em outro lugar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize um `TextView` com a propriedade `android:textIsSelectable=true`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_to_copy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />
```

Comment: Teria como eu adicionar esse textview em uma AlertDialog?

Comment: Sim, programaticamente ou via xml. Se quiser via xml, do jeito acima vc cria um layout com esse textview, e na hora de criar o dialog vc usa o método `setContentView` da classe Dialog

Comment: @HugoFernandes consegui resolver programaticamente usando o Clipboard, mas obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

*Minha solução:*

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DetalhesDebitosActivity.this);
                                        //alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(result);

                                        final TextView input = new TextView(DetalhesDebitosActivity.this);
                                        alertDialogBuilder.setView(input);

                                        input.setText(result);

                                        input.setTextIsSelectable(true);


                                        input.setGravity(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_GRAVITY);
                                        input.setTextSize(16);


        /*
                                        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                                            }
                                        });*/


                                        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Copiar",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

                                                clipboard.setText(input.getText().toString());
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Linha digitável copiada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                finish();


                                            }
                                        });



                                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                                        alertDialog.show();
```